Plotting a function in an SVG element : can the viewbox be the function plotting range?
I am plotting some math functions in the domain x: [0, 0.01], y: [0, 1] using JS and SVG elements.
My first approach was to scale the x-axis in order to have a "good" aspect ratio (for instance, multiply all the x coordinates by 1000 so my aspect ratio is 10:1).
To keep things as simple as possible, I would like to remove this scale factor and make the viewBox attribute to be related to my function plotting range (for instance, i would like to set viewBox="0 0 0.01 1" so i don't have to scale all x-coordinates).
Is this possible and recommended ?
I tried using preserveAspectRatio="none" on my svg element and vector-scaling="non-scaling-stroke" on its children, but things are not as crisp as with my first approach.
